# MSMQ with transactional support and Transport security

Tags: msmq

I am looking for a working reference sample MSMQ remote receive and remote send with transactional support and transport level security.

I have looked into Microsoft documentation and it talks about Message Encryption in theory but I couldn't see a sample.

I knew about WCF implementation however it does only MSMQ as a transit during client to server whereas I am looking for a console client to push a message from a server and later the message could be received by some other client from another server.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm confused, MSMQ supports sending messages over HTTP, which, I'm assuming, can also be done over HTTPS? And as long as you know the path to the queue anyone can retrieve it should you give it enough permissions

Comment: Importantly, TLS only secures the transport, not the message.  If your intent is to ultimately queue an encrypted message, you'll have to use message-level encryption—which involves a cert/keys accessible by both the sender and receiver.

WCF does support message-level encryption, but it seems you're interested in a pure MSMQ implementation—which MSMQ does not provide out-of-the-box.